# minmizing average problem

Tags: computer-science

Given a set containing N numbers, minimize the average where you can take out any string of consecutive numbers in the set.
|N|<=100000

Ex. {5, 1, 7, 8, 2}

You can take out {1,7}, etc. but the way to minimize in this case is just to take out {7,8} which will give a minimum average of (5+2+1)/3=2.667.

NOTE:-You can't use the first or last one, so you can't take out {5}  or {2}.
I want to know the general procedure to minimize this. I am looking for a linear solution.
thanks

Comment: The note is extremely unclear

Comment: We are not allowed to take out  first and last element from the set

Comment: So how is `{1}` considered the first or the last element in your example???

Comment: Sry that was by mistake i correct that

Comment: OK, now it is unclear how `{5,2}` is considered a string of consecutive numbers!!!

Comment: You are right {5,2} is not a string a consecutive numbers edit the question sry for the trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a $2$-dimensional table, with each cell $[i][j]$ indicating the sum of elements $i,i+1,\dots,j$:

```
n = array.length
table[0][0] = array[0]
for j = 1 to n-1:
    table[0][j] = table[0][j-1]+array[j]
for i = 1 to n-1:
    for j = i to n-1:
        table[i][j] = table[i-1][j-1]-array[i]+array[j]
```

Then, find the indexes (other than first and last) of the cell with the largest value:

```
max = array[1][1]
max_i = 1
max_j = 1
for i = 1 to n-2:
    for j = i to n-2:
        if max < table[i][j]:
            max = table[i][j]
            max_i = i
            max_j = j
return max_i,max_j
```

Given a set of $n$ elements, time complexity and space complexity are both $O(n^2)$.

Comment: supoose input contains {1,2,3,4,5} then table will look like similiar to this 1 3 6 10 15 ; 0 2 5 9 14 ; 0 0 3 7 12 ; 0 0 0 4 9 ; 0 0 0 0 5 then how it will proceed to the solution then

Comment: @user157920: he indexes of the cell with the largest value (indexes different than 0 and `n-1`, as dictated by the question at hand) would $[1][3]$, representing the sum $2+3+4$. And that's the solution for your example.

Comment: Is this a general soln I mean is this applicable to all types of testcases

Comment: @user157920: Why don't you run test-cases and find out?

Comment: Ok i will thanks for the rply

Comment: @user157920: You're welcome. See updated answer for how to retrieve the indexes and find the solution. Also, please feel free to accept this answer (by clicking on the V next to it) if it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The average is minimized by taking only the smallest value in the set, i.e. take out the largest elements.

By the restriction of first/last element and consecutive string, you would take out the consecutive inner string which has the biggest weighted average (stringlength/n*stringaverage) and bigger than the weighted average of first and last element (2/n*firstlastaverage).

Comment: but this requires to calculate the average of every possible combination of consecutive inner string so solution will have exponential complexity. This is a brute force technique , I am looking for a better solution

Comment: yes indeed; it is not entirely brute-force as you do not calculate the total average every time (just the string averages).you may think of some further restrictions on which inner strings to take, for example would not take any string containing "small" elements.

Comment: if n is of the order of 10^5 then it will take hours to resolve some of the test cases by this method as for calculating string average we need the string length for which we can have n-2-k+1Ck combinations for a substring of length k and k can vary from 1 to n-2 so not a god option to go with this I guess

Comment: yes but if you have nothing else..

Comment: I am sure there exist some sublinear solution to this problem , I am working on it , or may be someone else can help me out